# Can marketing efforts be considered to be a factor of production?

Tags: microeconomics

This is a sightly unconventional question, but I want to know whether marketing efforts can be considered as a factor of production. After all, if no one knows about your product, you can't make a profit. Also, marketing efforts may, in some or most cases, show diminishing returns. It is a kind of labor.

Answer (score 2):

Marketing is obviously relevant. We can observe that firms spend money on marketing. If it had no effect, they wouldn't do it. Whether it is a "factor of production" depends on your definition.

In my book, a factor of production is any input that *directly* contributes to the production (creation) of the good or service. That is, it enters some production function $f$ that maps "factors of production" into "output", a quantity of the produced good. In that sense, marketing is *not* a factor of production, because it has no *direct* effect on how many goods are produced. In my eyes, marketing is supposed to influence the *demanded* quantity, not the produced quantity. Of course the two are related, but not directly.

[Belleflamme and Peitz](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/economics/industrial-economics/industrial-organization-markets-and-strategies-2nd-edition) have a nice subsection on adverstising (6.1), where they discuss three distinct aspects of how advertising (which I use synonomously with marketing) affects demand: it can be persuasive, informative or complimentary. Such a distinction matters, because the welfare effects differ. For instance, informative ads may increase welfare as consumers can make better-informed choices, whereas persuasive ads may decrease welfare as it distorts consumers' real preferences.

Comment: Agreed. If there were an exogenous positive shock to demand, would that *necessarily* require increased use of advertising to produce more supply as we move up the supply curve? Clearly not.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Production factors include any human input by definition, and thus marketing efforts are included, needless to say.